# how to set the priority to get the mutex in C/c++

Tags: c++, c, windows, mutex, multiprocessing

I have 3 process (equal priority)

1. P1
2. P2
3. P3(timer)

priority to get the mutex is as follows: `P1(1 priority), P2(2 priority), P3(timer)(3 priority)`

If suppose `p3` comes and get the mutex
then `p2` comes and wait for mutex
after that p1 comes and it  also wait for mutex

if `p3` release mutex then `p1` should get the mutex not `p2`.

How to perform this in C or C++.

Note : all processes are running inside threads having same priority.

OS - windows Xp

Comment: There are some grammatical errors in here that make the question ambiguous. Can you please fix that?

Comment: It is stated (unfortunately I don't remember where right now), that even if p1 calls WaitForSingleObject(), and only afterwards p2 calls WaitForSingleObject(), it is still possible that p2 will obtain acquisition of the mutex before p1. So it more depends on the operating system's state rather than the threads' priority.

Comment: The question appears to be about multiprocessing, not multithreading. If this is true (i.e. you really have three processes to synchronize, not threads within a single process) then please fix the tags.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the threads have equal priority, which thread gets the lock will be rather arbitrary. It appears you want to wait on a condition variable rather than using a simple mutex. You will still have a mutex; condition variables are a concept on top of mutexes. Another possibility is to use synchronization barriers.

EDIT:
An example of using condition variables using the pthreads interface (C-style):
https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/pthreads/#ConVarSignal

An important question you need to ask yourself: With all of this waiting and synchronization, are you buying anything? The purpose of using threads is to let some things run in parallel. If that is not happening, you have a multithreaded application that runs slower than if the application didn't use threads at all.

Answer (score 2):

```
SetThreadPriority(
   HANDLE hThread,
   int nPriority
);
```

this function will set the priority of your threads .... the `HANDLE` value you will get while creating thread.. like

```
:HANDLE hf=_beginthred(abc,0,NULL)
```

Answer (score 1):

Making lock acquisition based on priority is a recipe for [deadlocks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deadlock). *Locking should always be done in predictable order, or you will have the classical (A,B), (B,A) deadlock possibility*.

You will instead want to work with a [priority queue](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Priority_queue) and let the lock itself be kernel managed. You could of course use a semaphore instead of a mutex to let the kernel know how many waiting threads to awake on queued items. However, you'll still want to lock the queue itself when accessing it

Comment: could you please expand on what you mean by let the lock be managed by the kernel?

Comment: instead of letting the threads tell the kernel what their priority is (it's essentially "fighting" over the locks) you could just post messages to a centralized queue, and use a synchronization primitive (e.g. a semaphore) to be notified about new messages - OSes have clear guarantees or policies on how they handle priorities and prevent thread starvation. This is what I mean with "let the kernel handle it".

Answer (score 0):

When you wait on a mutex, the process's thread is added in the mutex waiting queue (a linked list) and your only chance would be to have the possibility to change the selection behavior in the queue. Maybe Windows offers this possibility or maybe the queue is by default sorted by priority (which is the most likely).

The fact that your processes have the same priority is not a problem since a thread timeslice will be function of the process **and** thread priority.